# How to troubleshoot Visual Studio keyboard mapping

Tags: visual-studio-2012

This is the one glaring annoyance (for me) with Visual Studio 2012. I have had it installed on 3 different machines and I get this problem all the time. SHIFT+ALT+F10 (show smart tag) will work for a period of time, but then it will stop working until I restart VS.

Has anyone else had this problem and fixed it? Or does anyone know how to troubleshoot it?